# Get a valid ID of the HTML field in EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using the code below to create the id for one element in my editor template, is there another way to get a valid id in the editor template?

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix.Replace('.', '_');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@{
    var id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: thanks. This solution resolved my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137235/how-to-work-with-nested-property-in-tinymce-in-asp-net-mvc