# How to work with nested property in tinyMCE in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, tinymce, mvc-editor-templates

Using the tiny MCE editor template in ASP.NET MVC provided as sample via Nuget.
In this template there is a call to tinymce method as below:

```
$('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)').tinymce({ . . .  });
```

At runtime this changes to

```
$('#fieldId').tinymce({ . . . });
```

It was working fine until the property which this was targeting was in the model itself. But when I moved the property inside another property, it stopped working. Now the field is like ModelView.SomeModel.TinyMceField.

I looked at the code that was rendered, it is:

```
$('#MyModel.Description').tinymce({. . .});
```

Earlier this was:

```
$('#Description').tinymce({. . .});
```

The field id changed from `Description` to `MyModel_Description`. So the issue is the different ("." (dot) and "_" (underscore)) "id" used in textarea and tinymce method call.

How to solve this ?
What should I change in :

```
$('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)').tinymce({ . . .  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution:

```
$('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(string.Empty)').tinymce({. . .})
```